# ipython notebook cannot see anaconda on Mac

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a Macbook and anaconda python is working perfectly in a terminal window, but the python modules are not seen when I use ipython notebook which launches in the browser, e.g. 
    import pandas
    ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: One way is to put the anaconda path in a .profile, and then ipython notebook --profile= ...

Comment: This probably means you are starting the notebook from a different installation than Anaconda.